# SQL Injection, The way of commenting

Tags: php, html, anchor

I'm working with injections and tricks behind them so I came across with the way of commenting  MySQL queries by `#`.

As all we know about using named anchors in HTML, in this case of injecting to URL, `#` works like an HTML named anchor and doesn't mean harmful for running the query.

The question is why this happens and why PHP doesn't include `#` as the rest of the input directly? *(e.g. ?id=2547#)*

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name see here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comments.html

Comment: In the context of browsers, the `#` as an anchor indicator is handled purely within the browser itself and (as far as I'm aware) no browser sends it to the server as part of the request; so it's never received by the server and can't be passed on to PHP

Comment: @MarkBaker What if the input is saved like that in database?

Comment: How about you just opt to use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli)? That should solve your .. emm ... problems.

Comment: @tereško *that's just the way of learning!*

Comment: Well, it was tag that confused me. If this question is about sending some symbols from browser to server, it's clearer now

Comment: @revo so, what exactly are you learning by doing something utterly wrong? Typing?

Comment: @YourCommonSense it's not your question and I asked it in the aspect of SQL injection. Don't remove tags based on your opinion, the others will down vote then :)

Comment: There are no aspects of SQL injections in the way browsers work.

Comment: @tereško that was practical however so we are here to make our wrongs true.

Comment: @YourCommonSense change the OP to yourself then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashes are handled locally by the browser, not sent to the server. E.g. if you write a URL

```
http://yourdomain.com/script.php?param=foo#id=1234#
```

the browser just sends `GET /script.php?param=foo` to the server. When the response comes back, it searches for the `id=1234` anchor in the HTML and scrolls down to it.

If you want to send the comment to the server, it needs to be percent-encoded:

```
http://yourdomain.com/script.php?param=foo%23id=1234%23
```

Comment: What if the input is saved like that in database?

Comment: Then it has nothing to do with query strings in the URL.

Comment: Data in the database is not executed as SQL code, unless you inject it back into some other query.

Answer (score 0):

Since the browser considers it a special character and it's not url encoded, when the browser encounters the `#` it assumes that the previous GET parameter (if it existed) has ended.

If it is url encoded and the input is not properly sanitized then it does in fact pose an injection threat, otherwise if the user input is properly sanitized I would not worry about this.

**Edit:**

If the database allows for such input (e.g. varchar2) and the html-special-chars get properly escaped during input, then of course the database will save the user input as they will in fact be just symbols and will not have any special meaning.